# How to create a class for simulated time?

Tags: c#, class, datetime

I want to create a class that simulates times. Here is what I have so far.

```
namespace TimeSimulationConsole
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Time startTime = new Time();
        startTime.Day = 1;
        startTime.Month = 1;
        startTime.Year = 2000;

        DateTime gameDate = DateTime.Parse(startTime.Day, startTime.Month, startTime.Year);
        Console.WriteLine(gameDate);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

class Time
{
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
}
```

I basically want to define a start time, that I can later modify, or add days to it. But for now I just want to convert it to DateTime and show it via console.

The code I wrote doesn't work, it seems I can't parse startTime.

Comment: [`DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) is for parsing a datetime from a string. What you want is one of the [DateTime constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I need read about this again. Some of the things still don't stick even after watching Microsoft lessons. All of it is so complicated to remind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Time startTime = new Time();
        startTime.Day = 1;
        startTime.Month = 1;
        startTime.Year = 2000;

        DateTime gameDate = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day);
        Console.WriteLine(gameDate);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Time
{
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you so much. I think I need to go back to the lessons about DateTime... still can't remind all of this stuff. Seems like watching a course one time is not enough.